# Image is not loading when loaded using ImageLoader

Tags: android, imageloader

I am trying to set an image from url using ImageLoader.

Here is my code

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_image)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();


        // Stop running tasks on this image if there are unfinished some
        ImageLoader.getInstance().cancelDisplayTask(mPostPhotoImageView);
        // Load the image

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, mPostPhotoImageView, options);
```

I don't understand, why is  this happening.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: internet permission?

Comment: @Kaushal28 All permissios are given

Comment: @Piyush Issue is that, image is not getting loaded

Comment: no error logs ?

Comment: yeah no error logs

Comment: @Mansuu.... What is your image url ?

Comment: @Piyush https://qilodemo.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1/corporate_softboard/IMG_20170508_152142_1_2fbea4be-e612-46db-81a7-a2c07277a2a9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Picasso library?
I find it much easier to use to load images from an url, all you need is an imageView and url as arguments.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("URLHERE").into(imageView);
```

I'd also check your permissions, especially asking them on runtime, just in case (though this shouldn't be the issue)

Comment: this is not the OP asking for.

Comment: @A.Xu  Image loader is  being used in my entire application, I can't afford using another library for doing the same.

Comment: Picasso is free and open-source, if that's what you mean. If you're using it in the entire application, does that mean that in other instances ImageLoader works? Or does it fail everywhere you use it?